# I reinstalled qt creator to fix error but it created more errors

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use QT Creator to create a simple square but I get 14 errors when compiling. It seems like the compiler doesnt reconize the functions.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    //Create Scene
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();

    //Creat Item To Put Into Scene
    QGraphicsRectItem * rect = new QGraphicsRectItem();
    rect->setRect(100, 50, 100, 100);

    //Add Item To Scene aka buffer
    scene->addItem(rect);

    //add a view
    QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Compile Output:**

```
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\MYGAME.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
Makefile.Debug:61: recipe for target 'debug\MYGAME.exe' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/lisa/Documents/build-MYGAME-QT_5_8-Debug'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
19:18:13: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project MYGAME (kit: QT 5.8)
The kit QT 5.8 has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
19:18:13: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

**Issues:**
[Screenshoted Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O9bn.png)

Comment: "The kit QT 5.8 has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem." You can find the settings for the kit in Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Kits. Look for warnings on that tab.

Comment: @ MrEricSir It says error: no compiler set in kit